# Adding a Custom Menu Fields

Tags: routes

I am new to Drupal and I am trying to create a menu (top navigation links) where a small description would be visible under the main Title.

I am trying to replicate [this](http://www.camdencounty.com/) sites menu.

Is there any module that would allow me to do this? Or is there something I missing that would allow the Description that you type to show up the way I am looking for. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I personally cant see any custom description from the site you have provided, unless you mean the tooltip box that shows after hovering a menu item for a few seconds.

Comment: If you look on that site, you will notice that the main navigation has a Main Title. And then a small description under neath. So the first one would be "Your Government" with a description of "Board of Freeholders, County Services, Taxes, Voter Information"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7).

A menu item's description is by default output as a tooltip (ie, in the `title` attribute).  Here's [a thread](http://drupal.org/node/1600970) that shows how to do take advantage of that using `hook_menu_link()` to achieve more or less the result you want.

Comment: I'm sorry.. Everything I have tried is not working. I found spots where people say just replace the navigation portion and replace with the code provided into my template.php file.. Other that want you to change the menu.inc file. Nothing is working. Can you give me a better sense of where exactly I need to make the change.. Would it be in the template file? Do I keep the existing call to the navigation and add the function to it which is pulling the new code for description?

Comment: Yes, you implement theme_menu_link() in your theme's template.php file. (You definitely do not want to edit menu.inc -- aka "hacking core".)